# boto3's atomic test and create?

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

In normal file systems is normal to have the pattern of trying to create a file and fail if it already existed to have the guarantee of being creating a unique filename.
How can the same be achieved with S3 : if I have many parallel tasks creating keys with random names on S3, how can I "test and write" atomically to guarantee that chances don't create a race and I end with messed data ?

Thanks

Comment: Does each parallel task have a unique identifier (eg a Task ID) that could be appended to a random object name?

Comment: I looked into it , but was cumbersome to use as the unique activity token could be up to 1024 bytes. Found a solution answered below.

Comment: By the way, what is your use-case for this requirement? If you are trying to capture continuous, streaming data, it might be better to use Kinesis.

Comment: The scenario is simpler: A distributed application using SWF, needs to transfer data among activities in "spool" areas of S3. Too paranoic you might say, but just would like to guarantee that the key that I randomly select to my spool will not be overwriten by a parallel execution of the flow. In SWF every task has its own task token guranteed to be unique by AWS, but like I said is 104 bytes long which is the maximum allowed by S3 for a key and cumbersome to visualize and pass around..

Answer (score 1):

After a few days of thinking, I believe I have found a very decent solution to my own problem: activate versioning on bucket and save freely the key name you want. From the answer take versionId and encode the object url in a agreed format (e.g.  s3://your-bucket/your-key?versionId=XXXXX ) . This url refers always to the object you wanted to save in the first place with no possibility of clashes/races.